# Change Camera Face Direction

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am just starting with 3D in Delphi, and am trying to understand what the camera RotationAngle is used for.  I had presumed it was to specify the direction and angle of the camera.  I have set up a small test bed for this.  It has a camera with 6 cubes around it.  I assume that the camera is initially pointing toward the back of the scene.

Changing RotationAngle X should make it turn to the bottom, front, top and back, in that order.  However in my test bed it goes bottom, top and back, missing the step for front.

Changing RotationAngle Y should make it turn to the right, front, left and back, in that order. However in my test bed it goes right, left and back, again missing the step for front.

Have i got the use for RotationAngle wrong? If so, what should I be using.

This is the code:

```
    unit MainForm;
    
    interface
    
    uses
      System.SysUtils, FMX.Forms, FMX.Materials, System.Math.Vectors, FMX.Types3D, FMX.Objects3D, FMX.Controls3D, FMX.Viewport3D,
      System.Classes, FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Layouts, FMX.MaterialSources, System.Types, System.UITypes,
      FMX.Controls.Presentation, FMX.StdCtrls, FMX.Edit;

type

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Viewport3D: TViewport3D;
    LayoutMain: TLayout;
    LightMaterialSource1: TLightMaterialSource;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    grpPosition: TGroupBox;
    Camera1: TCamera;
    CubeLeft: TCube;
    CubeRight: TCube;
    grpAngle: TGroupBox;
    ColorMaterialSource2: TColorMaterialSource;
    CubeBottom: TCube;
    CubeTop: TCube;
    CubeBack: TCube;
    CubeFront: TCube;
    ColorMaterialSource1: TColorMaterialSource;
    ColorMaterialSource3: TColorMaterialSource;
    ColorMaterialSource4: TColorMaterialSource;
    ColorMaterialSource5: TColorMaterialSource;
    ColorMaterialSource6: TColorMaterialSource;
    AngleX: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    Button2: TButton;
    Button3: TButton;
    AngleY: TEdit;
    Button4: TButton;
    Button5: TButton;
    AngleZ: TEdit;
    Button6: TButton;
    Button7: TButton;
    PositionZ: TEdit;
    Button8: TButton;
    Button9: TButton;
    PositionY: TEdit;
    Button10: TButton;
    Button11: TButton;
    PositionX: TEdit;
    Button12: TButton;
    txtStep: TEdit;
    procedure ChangePosition(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ChangeAngle(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure txtStepExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ChangeAngleText(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ChangePositionText(Sender: TObject);
  private
    Step: Single;
    procedure UpdateCameraPosition;
    procedure UpdateCameraAngle;
  public
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.ChangeAngle(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case TButton(Sender).Tag of
    0: Camera1.RotationAngle.X := Camera1.RotationAngle.X - Step;
    1: Camera1.RotationAngle.X := Camera1.RotationAngle.X + Step;
    2: Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := Camera1.RotationAngle.Y - Step;
    3: Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := Camera1.RotationAngle.Y + Step;
    4: Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := Camera1.RotationAngle.Z - Step;
    5: Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := Camera1.RotationAngle.Z + Step;
  end;
  UpdateCameraAngle;
end;

procedure TForm1.ChangeAngleText(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case TEdit(Sender).Tag of
    0: Camera1.RotationAngle.X := StrToFloat(AngleX.Text);
    1: Camera1.RotationAngle.Y := StrToFloat(AngleY.Text);
    2: Camera1.RotationAngle.Z := StrToFloat(AngleZ.Text);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ChangePosition(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case TButton(Sender).Tag of
    0: Camera1.Position.X := Camera1.Position.X - Step;
    1: Camera1.Position.X := Camera1.Position.X + Step;
    2: Camera1.Position.Y := Camera1.Position.Y - Step;
    3: Camera1.Position.Y := Camera1.Position.Y + Step;
    4: Camera1.Position.Z := Camera1.Position.Z - Step;
    5: Camera1.Position.Z := Camera1.Position.Z + Step;
  end;
  UpdateCameraPosition;
end;

procedure TForm1.ChangePositionText(Sender: TObject);
begin
  case TEdit(Sender).Tag of
    0: Camera1.Position.X := StrToFloat(PositionX.Text);
    1: Camera1.Position.Y := StrToFloat(PositionY.Text);
    2: Camera1.Position.Z := StrToFloat(PositionZ.Text);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Step := StrToFloat(txtStep.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.txtStepExit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Step := StrToFloat(txtStep.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateCameraAngle;
begin
  AngleX.Text := Format('%3.2f', [Camera1.RotationAngle.X]);
  AngleY.Text := Format('%3.2f', [Camera1.RotationAngle.Y]);
  AngleZ.Text := Format('%3.2f', [Camera1.RotationAngle.Z]);
end;

procedure TForm1.UpdateCameraPosition;
begin
  PositionX.Text := Format('%3.2f', [Camera1.Position.X]);
  PositionY.Text := Format('%3.2f', [Camera1.Position.Y]);
  PositionZ.Text := Format('%3.2f', [Camera1.Position.Z]);
end;

end.
```

This is the form:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 592
  ClientWidth = 713
  FormFactor.Width = 320
  FormFactor.Height = 480
  FormFactor.Devices = [Desktop]
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  DesignerMasterStyle = 0
  object LayoutMain: TLayout
    Align = Client
    Size.Width = 713.000000000000000000
    Size.Height = 592.000000000000000000
    Size.PlatformDefault = False
    TabOrder = 2
    object Viewport3D: TViewport3D
      Align = Client
      Camera = Camera1
      Size.Width = 533.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 592.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      UsingDesignCamera = False
      object Camera1: TCamera
        AngleOfView = 45.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
      end
      object CubeRight: TCube
        Position.X = 4.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        TwoSide = True
        MaterialSource = ColorMaterialSource2
      end
      object CubeLeft: TCube
        Position.X = -4.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        TwoSide = True
        MaterialSource = ColorMaterialSource1
      end
      object CubeBottom: TCube
        Position.Y = -4.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        TwoSide = True
        MaterialSource = ColorMaterialSource5
      end
      object CubeTop: TCube
        Position.Y = 4.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        TwoSide = True
        MaterialSource = ColorMaterialSource6
      end
      object CubeBack: TCube
        Position.Z = -4.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        TwoSide = True
        MaterialSource = ColorMaterialSource3
      end
      object CubeFront: TCube
        Position.Z = 4.000000000000000000
        Width = 1.000000000000000000
        Height = 1.000000000000000000
        Depth = 1.000000000000000000
        TwoSide = True
        MaterialSource = ColorMaterialSource4
      end
      object ColorMaterialSource2: TColorMaterialSource
        Color = claSpringgreen
        Left = 344
        Top = 280
      end
      object ColorMaterialSource1: TColorMaterialSource
        Color = claRed
        Left = 272
        Top = 288
      end
      object ColorMaterialSource3: TColorMaterialSource
        Color = claYellow
        Left = 360
        Top = 296
      end
      object ColorMaterialSource5: TColorMaterialSource
        Color = claPink
        Left = 376
        Top = 312
      end
      object ColorMaterialSource6: TColorMaterialSource
        Color = claOrange
        Left = 384
        Top = 320
      end
      object ColorMaterialSource4: TColorMaterialSource
        Color = claViolet
        Left = 368
        Top = 304
      end
    end
    object Panel1: TPanel
      Align = Right
      Position.X = 533.000000000000000000
      Size.Width = 180.000000000000000000
      Size.Height = 592.000000000000000000
      Size.PlatformDefault = False
      TabOrder = 0
      object grpPosition: TGroupBox
        Position.X = 5.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 134.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 169.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 123.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Text = 'Position'
        TabOrder = 1
        object Button7: TButton
          Tag = 5
          Position.X = 139.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 87.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 41
          Text = '>'
          OnClick = ChangePosition
        end
        object PositionZ: TEdit
          Tag = 2
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 38
          Text = '0.00'
          Position.X = 35.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 87.000000000000000000
        end
        object Button8: TButton
          Tag = 4
          Position.X = 9.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 87.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 40
          Text = '<'
          OnClick = ChangePosition
        end
        object Button9: TButton
          Tag = 3
          Position.X = 139.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 55.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 44
          Text = '>'
          OnClick = ChangePosition
        end
        object PositionY: TEdit
          Tag = 1
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 39
          Text = '0.00'
          Position.X = 35.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 55.000000000000000000
        end
        object Button10: TButton
          Tag = 2
          Position.X = 9.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 55.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 43
          Text = '<'
          OnClick = ChangePosition
        end
        object Button11: TButton
          Tag = 1
          Position.X = 139.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 23.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 45
          Text = '>'
          OnClick = ChangePosition
        end
        object PositionX: TEdit
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 42
          Text = '0.00'
          Position.X = 35.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 23.000000000000000000
          OnExit = ChangePositionText
        end
        object Button12: TButton
          Position.X = 9.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 23.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 46
          Text = '<'
          OnClick = ChangePosition
        end
      end
      object grpAngle: TGroupBox
        Position.X = 5.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 5.000000000000000000
        Size.Width = 169.000000000000000000
        Size.Height = 124.000000000000000000
        Size.PlatformDefault = False
        Text = 'Angle'
        TabOrder = 0
        object AngleX: TEdit
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 42
          Text = '0.00'
          Position.X = 34.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
          OnExit = ChangeAngleText
        end
        object Button1: TButton
          Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 46
          Text = '<'
          OnClick = ChangeAngle
        end
        object Button2: TButton
          Tag = 1
          Position.X = 138.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 24.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 45
          Text = '>'
          OnClick = ChangeAngle
        end
        object Button3: TButton
          Tag = 3
          Position.X = 138.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 44
          Text = '>'
          OnClick = ChangeAngle
        end
        object AngleY: TEdit
          Tag = 1
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 39
          Text = '0.00'
          Position.X = 34.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
          OnExit = ChangeAngleText
        end
        object Button4: TButton
          Tag = 2
          Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 56.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 43
          Text = '<'
          OnClick = ChangeAngle
        end
        object Button5: TButton
          Tag = 5
          Position.X = 138.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 88.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 41
          Text = '>'
          OnClick = ChangeAngle
        end
        object AngleZ: TEdit
          Tag = 2
          Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
          TabOrder = 38
          Text = '0.00'
          Position.X = 34.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 88.000000000000000000
          OnExit = ChangeAngleText
        end
        object Button6: TButton
          Tag = 4
          Position.X = 8.000000000000000000
          Position.Y = 88.000000000000000000
          Size.Width = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.Height = 22.000000000000000000
          Size.PlatformDefault = False
          TabOrder = 40
          Text = '<'
          OnClick = ChangeAngle
        end
      end
      object txtStep: TEdit
        Touch.InteractiveGestures = [LongTap, DoubleTap]
        TabOrder = 37
        Text = '2.00'
        Position.X = 43.000000000000000000
        Position.Y = 263.000000000000000000
        OnExit = txtStepExit
      end
    end
  end
  object LightMaterialSource1: TLightMaterialSource
    Diffuse = claWhite
    Ambient = xFF202020
    Emissive = claNull
    Specular = xFF606060
    Shininess = 30
    Left = 436
    Top = 56
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your test application and keeping the position at (0, 0, 0), the rotation seems to work as you expect, contrary to what you claim it does.

Rotating around x-axis (button 2):
violet - pink - yellow - brown - violet

Rotating around y-axis (button 4):
violet - green - yellow - red - violet

Rotating around z-axis (button 6):
rotates the violet square.

Zooming out (third position setting) -15

- violet becomes hidden by the yellow cube, all others are visible
- at rotation of 15 the cube constellation image is rotated -15

So, when rotating the camera around the selected axis the view changes according to expectations.